# Could not find or load main class?

Tags: java, macos, compilation, terminal

So I compiled a java file (all in OS X terminal) and now when I try to run it, it's giving me the "Could not find or load main class" error.  Here's the command:

> java -cp "./mysql-connector-java-bin.jar" JavaFile

The mysql connector jar file is in the same directory as the JavaFile but I think it's just not able to find the JavaFile?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add current directory too to the class path. Something like -

```
java -cp "./mysql-connector-java-bin.jar:." JavaFile
```

This will include all files in the current directory including your mysql connector jar and your runnable class file.

Comment: You said it's in the same directory. So just include current directory in classpath as shown in above answer.

Comment: Generally if you have to add multiple jar files in different file location you can do `java -cp "dir1/test1.jar:dir2/test2.jar" MyClass`

Comment: oh i see i see alright then it looks like I'm getting a different error now "no suitable driver found".. I'm guessing that has nothing to do with the jar file?

Comment: That has everything to do with the jar file . Two possibilities - If you are using java 7 then simply adding jar in class path should do the trick. However if you are using Java 6 or lower version you need to explicitly load the class using `Class.forName()` method.

Comment: I'm using java version 1.8.0_40 so when you say adding the jar to the class path do you mean like adding it like this? java -cp "mysql-connector-java-bin.jar" JavaFile

Comment: Yes. If you are using Java 8 then you don't have to load the driver class using `Class.forName()`. All you have to do is add the jar is classpath as you have mentioned. You can try `java -cp "./mysql-connector-java-bin.jar:."  JavaFile` though I don't see how is this different from just adding current dir in class path.

Comment: I don't really get why it's so weird but that worked :D all I have to do now is figure out why it's trying to send password "YES" to access the mysql database.. thanks a lot for your help!